# Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[NGXLogger -> LoggerConfig]

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have following problem.
When I unit test a project "A" I get 45 from 45 item green.
Now I add a component "B". 
When I start the unit testing now,
I get a two error **on a component of project "A"**.

The error looks like that:

```
 MainNavComponent should render some nav links   Error:
      StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[NGXLogger -> LoggerConfig]:   
   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NGXLogger -> LoggerConfig]: 
       NullInjectorError: No provider for LoggerConfig!
    Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[NGXLogger -> LoggerConfig]: 
      StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NGXLogger -> LoggerConfig]:  
    NullInjectorError: No provider for LoggerConfig!
```

As I said, the "`MainNavComponent`" is part of project "A", which was without errors without the new component "B".

**How it could come?
How to clear this problem?**

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: Are you using your component B in your MainNavComponent ?

Comment: Yes!
(sorry, I forgot to notice that.)

Comment: I tryed many different thinks, also implementing LoggerModule in b.component.ts, b.service.ts, main-nac.component.ts as a provider.

Comment: Please post your code. As @Orodan noticed, you already forgot to state something very important.

Comment: @trichetriche Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just because I am a newbee and would have needed a more specific answer ..

It's in the tests, more specific the `file.component.spec.ts`

```
beforeEach(async () => {
  await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [AppTestingModule],
    declarations: [YourComponent],
    providers: [
      { provide: LoggerConfig, useClass: class {}}
    ]
  }).compileComponents();
});
```

..  hope that helps everyone to solve the issue faster.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as writen in the error log.
I need to inject LoggerConfig in main-nav.component.ts.

Sorry, so simple, dit not recognize before.

Comment: I added to the provider list.
So I inject it.

Comment: Yeah that what I though, maybe you should edit your answer and use "inject" instead of "implement" then. It might be confusing otherwise :)

Comment: @Orodan I dit. Thanks.